# Twisted: putChild AttributeError while building site tree

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to implement site tree using the following code:

```
root = Root()
a = root.putChild("login", login())
b = root.putChild("user", user())
c = b.putChild("register", register())
```

I expect the it will generate structure like this:

```
http://www.example.com/login
http://www.example.com/user
http://www.example.com/user/register
```

But, unfortunately I receive the following error message instead:

```
2013-10-11 19:33:15+0300 [-] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'putChild'
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `user` a class implementing `twisted.web.resource.IResource`?

In that case,

```
u = user()
root.putChild("user", u)
u.putChild("register", register())
```

Method `putChild` returns `None`, not the child as you seem to have expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Max for your fast response. Solution is working perfectly, and as expected.